# How to access different node on, onUpdate event in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a firebase database which has two firebase nodes in the same level. One named NotificaationKey and one named requests. I have an onUpdate cloud function on requests/status field. When the node gets updated I get a field from requests node and use it to retrieve data from the NotificationKey node, but when I access the Notification node I get the following response instead of the data I want. It is printing following log.
[image: log1]
[image: log2]
[image: log3]
[image: log4]
Following is the code how I access the database. on onUpdate function.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.notifyUser = functions.database.ref('/requests/{requestId}/status')
.onUpdate(event => {
    const adminRefVar = event.data.adminRef.root;

    return event.data.adminRef.parent.child('requestorId').once('value').then((snapshot)=>{
        var uuid = snapshot.val();
        console.log("Data : "+uuid );

        return adminRefVar.child('/NotificationKey').orderByChild('uuid').equalTo(uuid)
        .once('value').then((snapshot2)=>{
            console.log("data: " + snapshot2);
            for(var i in snapshot2)
            {
                console.log("data in snap: "+snapshot2[i]);
            }

            return snapshot2;
        });
    });
});
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and I'm new to node.js and firebase functions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access a different node by below code. Hope it would help someone.

```
exports.notifyUser = functions.database.ref('/requests/{requestId}/status').onUpdate(event => {
const adminRefVar = event.data.ref.firestore;

return event.data.adminRef.parent.child('requestorId').once('value').then((snapshot)=>{
    var uuid = snapshot.val();
    return admin.database().ref('NotificationKey').orderByChild('uuid').equalTo(uuid).once('value').then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        var value = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log("notification key : " + value.notificationKey);
        const payload = {
            notification:{
                title:'CLUTS request status has been updated',
                body: 'Your ride share request has been '+event.data.val(),
                badge: '1',
                sound: 'default'
            }
        };
        var userToken;
        userToken = value.notificationKey;
        return admin.messaging().sendToDeviceGroup(userToken, payload)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            return 0;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            return 0;
        });
      });
       return snapshot;
    });
  });
});
```